# All in One Calendar Plugin Custom Post Type Query

Tags: query, calendar, plugin-events-calendar

Hi I'm trying to write a query which will pull the events out from the All in One Calendar Plugin. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php  query_posts('post_type=ai1ec_event');?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php echo '<h5><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h5>'; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?><!--  End the Loop -->
```

This works well to get the event titles and their respective content, but I need to get the event details out as well. eg. event dates, venue, location.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try: 
<?php echo $location; ?>
<?php echo $categories; ?>
<?php echo $calendar_url; ?>
etc.
as found in event-single.php

Comment: Thanks Pontus, I gave it a try but no joy.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so hope this helps someone. Unless you want to query the database directly, the trick is to include the following:

```
$event = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_event($post->ID);
```

thereafter you can retrieve the variables, for example:

```
            <?php  query_posts('post_type=ai1ec_event');?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php $event = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_event($post->ID); ?>

            <?php echo '<h5><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h5>'; ?>

            <?php if( $event->multiday ) echo 'ai1ec-multiday' ?> <?php if( $event->allday ) echo 'ai1ec-allday' ?>

            <?php echo esc_html( $event->start_time ) ?>

            <?php echo $event->timespan_html ?>

            <?php echo $event->venue; ?>

            <?php if( $recurrence ): ?>
            <?php echo $recurrence ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if( $event->cost ): ?>
            <?php echo esc_html( $event->cost ) ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if( $contact ): ?>
            <?php echo $contact ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if( $categories ): ?>
            <?php echo $categories ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if( $tags ): ?>
                <?php echo $tags ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?><!--  End the Loop -->
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer.  I will use this info to insert a related event into the single-post template of a custom post type of mine.

Answer (score 0):

date is in UNIX format. So I convert it:

```
$eventdate = $event->start; 
$mydate = date('M d, Y', $eventdate);
echo $mydate
```

Long time I'm can't get the post content and find a solution:

```
$text = $event->post->post_content;
echo $text;
```

perhaps useful to someone

Comment: I believe this may be a valid answer but I find it very hard to understand. Can you try to make it more clear?