# All in one calendar custom post type query doesnt work as expected

Tags: custom-post-types, query, calendar

I did a custom post query for AIO Events Calendar, as described here: [All in One Calendar Plugin Custom Post Type Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54546/all-in-one-calendar-plugin-custom-post-type-query)

But it doesnt work.

```
<?php echo esc_html( $event->cost ) ?>
```

returns the cost, but

```
<?php echo $contact ?>
```

and any other variable without $event-> returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that comes out of this query-- `$event = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_event($post->ID);`-- will need the `$event->` part. That is how you access data from an object. That is just pure PHP.

I don't know why some of the values [in that answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54546/all-in-one-calendar-plugin-custom-post-type-query), like `$contact`, are not prefixed with `$event->` but I am assuming those variables do not come from from that query.

Add `var_dump($event);` immediately after `$event = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_event($post->ID);` and you can see what information is in that object.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, the variables that I got from var_dump have different names than the variables without $event->. Thats why prefixing them didnt work. Now I have everything I need.